# Reference Check. Find, Match, Conbination

Tags: vba, excel

I will be attempting to make this clear and understandable has this is my fist post and question. I have bank feeds in a cell that contains text and number. In another sheet I have all my reference number that I ask people to add when making a payment which then is display in the bank feeds of cell mentioned (not all the time).  I am attempting to do a vba or formula to do the following :

**Formula explanation**: look into the reference column (1000+ Cells) then look into bank feed column if contains similar reference number or exact = reference number

**BANK FEEDS COLUMN**

```
00025 LARRY AUS T

REF 00035 INTRO LTD

INV 00058 

REFERENCE00152TA
```

**REFERENCE COLUMN**

```
00025
00035
00058
```

**RESULT**

```
BANK FEEDS COLUMN            FORMULA RESULT COLUMNS

00025 LARRY AUS T            00025
REF 00035 INTRO LTD          00035
INV 00058                    00058
REFERENCE00152TA             NO FOUND
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to the forum. Start by posting the code you have and read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Of course it's done by VBA, but also possible with some additional cells and formula. What you need is `find`, `indirect` + `adress`, `match`, etc. Sample sheet is [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qXmljzbIBBmefJUK6ivT_8m1PDsF_4WSk50a7QHzbNI/).

[image]

Formula may look like overly complicated but it's needed for later changes or drag-fill. For example, below formula(`C2`) will still work even after inserting or deleting some columns.

```
=iferror(if(find(indirect("reference!"&address(column(C2)-column($C2)+1, 1)),$A2)>0, indirect("reference!"&address(column(C2)-column($C2)+1, 1)),))
```

If 'reference' is rather small and there's no need for considering column changes, you can hard-code column `C` to `E` like this for one row. Then drag to fill other rows.

```
=iferror(if(find(reference!A$1, $A2)>0, reference!A$1))
=iferror(if(find(reference!A$2, $A2)>0, reference!A$2))
=iferror(if(find(reference!A$3, $A2)>0, reference!A$3))
```

Of course, if you use 'named range' formulae can be even much simpler.
And if you want VBA, it can be done with double `for` loop too.